# Create own OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I think the question says it all: I want to create a custom OnItemClickListener for a ListView. I want to add and change the parameters for a OnItemClickListener but how can I create an own so it is called if I click on an Item in the ListView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222129/creating-a-custom-onclicklistener i think it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an interface first, then implement a method, where you set the listener in your custom class and already then make a main class to listen for your custom event

Interface:

```
public interface OnCustomEventListener{
  public void onEvent();   //can have parameters
}
```

method in your e.g. adapter:
    private OnCustomEventListener mListener; //field

```
//setter method
public void setCustomEventListener(OnCustomEventListener eventListener) {
   this.mListener=eventListener;
}
```

listener:

```
someObjectYouWantToHaveYourCustomListenerToBeAssignedFor.setCustomEventListener(new OnCustomEventListener(){
    public void onEvent(){
    //do whatever you want to do when the event is performed.
    }
});
```

how to call e.g. from your adapter:

```
if(this.mListener!=null){
   this.mListener.onEvent();
}
```

P.S. Your custom listener may have as many parameters as you want

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292712/android-custom-event-listener)

Comment: Thank you for that but there is one thing I don't understand. Why does the `OnCustomEventListener` know that it should call if I click on an item?

Comment: because `OnCustomEventListener` acts as a callback

Comment: I implement these three steps in my Classes but I can't recieve any ClickEvents

Comment: @Cilenco when do you call: `this.mListener.onEvent();` ?

Comment: I made a class which `extands ListView`. There I put the interface `OnCustomEventListener` and the method `setCustomEventListener(OnCustomEventListener eventListener)`. In my Activity I call `myListView.setCustomEventListener(new ...)` with the event inside.

Comment: @Cilenco can you use `Log.i(...)` in your custom class that `extends ListView` in that part where the event should be fired to see if it is actually being fired

Comment: I got it work a little bit. The event is fired on Activity start but not if I click on an item...

Comment: @Cilenco do not forget that you have to call ` this.mListener.onEvent();` every time you want your main class to know that the action got initiated

Comment: I think my problem is that I have to fire the event from the `onTouchEvent` Method right? How can I check for a Click in this method? Or do I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Cilenco well, yes, i believe so, i don't know how your code looks like, so I am not sure, but yes, you should fire event when some event occurs. Firing an event: `this.mListener.onEvent();`