# I have a recyclerview where there is an image for a popup menu. I want to know how to determine on which recyclerview item the popup menu has clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is my recyclerview item_courses.xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="20dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="121dp"

        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textColor="@color/testcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_span="30"
                android:text="Course Name"
                android:paddingBottom="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_course_menu"

                android:layout_span="3"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:onClick="CreatePopupMenu"
                android:layout_column="28" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:text="10 students"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/testcolor"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_span="13"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/testcolor"
                    android:layout_span="13"
                    android:layout_column="20" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is my recyclerview adapter

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
    .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
    .DataObjectHolder> {
private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<Person> mDataset;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View
        .OnClickListener {
    TextView subject;
    TextView studentno;
    TextView classno;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        studentno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        classno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getPosition(), v);

    }


}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Person> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_courses, parent, false);

    DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.subject.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
    holder.studentno.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
    holder.classno.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText3());

}

public void addItem(Person dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
    mDataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v); 
}
```

}

Suppose their is only one item named in popum menu (named : popup_menu.xml).

```
menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/option1"

    android:title="Option 1" />
```

So when it was clicked on option1. how to determine on which recyclerview item it was clicked ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222129/creating-a-custom-onclicklistener

Comment: @RuAware But when I click on an image there will be popup menu. so how do I add it into another class (MyOnClickListener)?

Comment: Can you please add a screen at least. Sounds like i worked on this problem for my current project?

Comment: @anik All the information are described in the question, I am not sure how screen image will help you ?

Answer (score 1):

Popup menu anchored to an `ImageView` (star) in a `RecyclerView` item:

[image: popup menu anchored to image view]

Position of `RecyclerView` item displayed when a popup menu item is selected:

[image: popup menu recyclerview item position]

To achieve this we need to modify your `DataObjectHolder` to do two things:

1. Anchor a popup menu to the image view when it is clicked.
2. Handle popup menu item click.

We use a custom listener, `PopupMenuListener` to pass the `RecyclerView` **item, its position in the adapter to be specific, hosting the popup menu that was just clicked**.

Modified `DataObjectHolder`:

```
public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View
        .OnClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private final MyClickListener myClickListener;
    private final PopupMenuListener popupMenuListener;
    TextView subject;
    TextView studentno;
    TextView classno;

    View imageView;

    public interface MyClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    public interface PopupMenuListener {
        void onPopupMenuClicked(MenuItem menuItem, int adapterPosition);
    }

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView, MyClickListener myClickListener, PopupMenuListener popupMenuListener) {
        super(itemView);

        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
        this.popupMenuListener = popupMenuListener;

        subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        studentno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        classno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        // Configure image view to show a popup menu when it is clicked:
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(view);
            }
        });

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);// IMPORTANT: 'getPosition()' is deprecated.
    }

  private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
      PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
      MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
      popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
      popup.show();
  }

    /*
     * Popup menu callback.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                // Call popup menu listener passing the menu item that was clicked as well as the recycler view item position:
                popupMenuListener.onPopupMenuClicked(item, getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Just implement `PopupMenuListener` and pass it to `DataObjectHolder`'s constructor and we're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter. XInfoHolder > {



public MyAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<Data> dataInfo) {

 ..........
 ........
}

@Override
public PersonInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    //* creating view from the layout for child element in the listview by using inflater*//*
    View itemView = ........
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonInfoHolder personInfoHolder, int i) {   ...
....

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class XInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected ImageView popupMenu;

    public XInfoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        popupMenu = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pop_up);
        popupMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (getLayoutPosition() == 0/something else && v.getId() == R.id.pop_up) {
            //show your popup all other place view is invisible
            //do whatever else here
        } 
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is how i solved this problem for my project. Thanks and best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand few things.Is id.pop_up the menu option (image) in the recyclerview ? how do I inflate the popup menu in onClick? And which part is used  to track the item from which the popup is clicked? Since I am newbie, may be these are stupid question but worth me a lot.

Comment: pop_up is your menu icon. When you click on that, then it will popup your item whatever you need to show..Thanks

Comment: How to inflate the popup now in onClick ?

Comment: make a view for that on the child of your Recycler view. Then View.GONE at the startup and View.VISIBLE when clicked

Comment: @Anik vai, I can not inflate the popupmenu into the onClick method. PopupMenu(Context context, View anchor). what will be the parameter of View anchor. If you show me a sample help me a lot.

Comment: My suggestion to make trick here that the view for popup will be invisible normal. When user will click on the menu icon, that time view will be visible. That is how i could solve. Let me know if u find any other solution.

Comment: How do you make the view visible ?

Comment: yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ---> to make visible                                   yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE or GONE); ---> to make invisible